# How to remove tomcat 9 from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall, tomcat, tomcat8

I know this question has been asked a lot but I am facing some problems. When I upload a war file to tomcat I cant get to to start and i get this error

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/fuseki] could not be started
```

I then have tried to remove tomcat 9 so I can install tomcat 8 but I cant follow the instructions given on other threads because when I run

```
dpkg -l|grep tomcat
```

returns nothing.

```
sudo apt-get remove tomcat
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'tomcat9' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get remove tomcat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tomcat
```

running the same but with tomcat9 instead of just tomcat returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'tomcat9' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
```

The server however is up and running and I can connect via the browser to the UI but I cant get to get a war file started.

Comment: How did you install Tomcat ?

Comment: I followed these instructions https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: So basically, you downloaded a tar.gz archive and unpacked it to /opt/tomcat. So `cd /opt` and `sudo rm -rf tomcat` should 'uninstall' it.

Comment: I did what you said but I hope it is the correct way and it purged everything and I can install tomcat 8 .

Comment: I did as you said and then installed tomcat 8.5 but I get the same error when I upload a .war file

Answer (score 3):

Since tomcat has been installed by unpacking a tar.gz file to /opt/tomcat, the uninstall process will be to remove /opt/tomcat.

```
cd /opt
sudo rm -rf tomcat
```